# Modify information displayed in shorthands/abbreviations list

Tags: biblatex, memoir, biblatex-chicago

In the `memoir` class with `biblatex`, the default behavior for the list of abbreviations generated with `\printshorthands` seems to be to give the author and title of the work, but not the full citation; and if several works in a row are from the same author, it will use the long dash in place of the author's name, as in the following example:

[image: excerpt from abbreviations list, showing partial citations and repeated authors]

I would instead like

1. the full reference for each work (as it would appear in the bibliography), and
2. each author to be spelled out in full (*unlike* the
   bibliography).

How can this be achieved? I'd hoped there would be
    some options to play with in `\printshorthands` but if they exist I
    haven't been able to find them, and I don't know which commands need
    modification otherwise.

Code for the above example as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}

@bookinbook{briocense1,
author = {Le Grant, Hervé},
authortype = {anon?},
editor = {Morice, Hyacinthe},
title = {Chronicon Briocense},
shorthand = {\emph{Chr. Brioc.}},
%pages = {1}
booktitle = {Mémoires pour servir de preuves à l'Histoire ecclésiastique et civile de Bretagne},
date = {1742},
%publisher = {Osmont},
address = {Paris},
keywords = {primary},
}

@book{briocense2,
author = {Le Grant, Hervé},
authortype = {anon?},
editor = {Le Duc, Gwenaël and Sterckx, Claude},
translator = {Le Duc, Gwenaël and Sterckx, Claude},
title = {Chronicon Briocense: Chronique de Saint-Brieuc (fin 14e siècle), éditée et traduite d'après les manuscrits BN 6003--BN 8899},
shorthand = {\emph{Chr. St-Brieuc}},
date = {1972},
volume = {1},
%publisher = {Imprimerie Simon},
address = {Rennes},
keywords = {primary},
}

@book{dargentre,
author = {d'Argentré, Bertrand},
title = {L'histoire de Bretaigne},
shorthand = {d'Argentré},
date = {1583},
%publisher = {J. Duclos},
address = {Rennes},
sortkey = {Argentré, Bertrand},
keywords = {secondary},
}

@book{1341docs,
editor = {Graham-Goering, Erika and Jones, Michael and Yeurc'h, Bertrand},
title = {Aux origines de la guerre de succession de Bretagne: Documents (1341--1342)},
shorthand = {\emph{Documents}},
year = {2019},
%publisher = {Presses Universitaires de Rennes/Société d’histoire et d’archéologie de Bretagne},
address = {Rennes},
keywords = {primary},
}

@book{duchesne,
author = {Du Chesne, André},
title = {Histoire de la Maison de Chastillon sur Marne},
shorthand = {Du Chesne},
date = {1621},
%publisher = {Cramoisy},
address = {Paris},
keywords = {secondary},
}

@book{froissartamiens,
shorthand = {Froissart Amiens},
author = {Froissart, Jean},
editor = {Diller, George T.},
title = {Chroniques: Livre I, le manuscrit d'Amiens},
date = {1991/1998},
%publisher = {Droz},
address = {Geneva},
keywords = {primary},
}

@book{froissart,
shorthand = {Froissart B},
author = {Froissart, Jean},
editor = {Luce, Siméon},
title = {Chroniques de J. Froissart},
date = {1869/1899},
%publisher = {Renouard},
address = {Paris},
keywords = {primary},
}

@book{froissartrome,
shorthand = {Froissart Rome},
author = {Froissart, Jean},
editor = {Diller, George T.},
title = {Chroniques: Dernière rédaction du premier livre, édition du manuscrit de Rome Reg. lat. 869},
date = {1972},
%publisher = {Droz},
address = {Geneva},
keywords = {primary},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true,useprefix=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\printshorthands

I will really back up this statement with some citations.\autocite{briocense1,briocense2,dargentre,1341docs,duchesne,froissartamiens,froissart,froissartrome}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The behaviour will *strongly* depend on the bibliography style that you use. Can you please show us a short example document and a few `.bib` entries that reproduce a list like the one in the screenshot.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you are much much much more likely to get any help if you provide a full, but minimal, example others can just copy and use as is. (3) as your question is here, we have to guess.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure if this was the kind of question that had a default answer or was context-specific; I'll try to get a MWE to edit in.

Comment: The usual behaviour of the `biblatex` standard styles is to print more or less the full bibliographic reference in the list of shorthands. Since this was not the case, you must have been using a custom style and the answer that works there can differ from case to case. (In this example `biblatex-chicago` had a convenient option, but this is not always guaranteed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` has the option `shorthandfull` to make the list of shorthands produce full bibliography entries.

You can get full given names instead of initials in the list of shorthands, but not anywhere else, if you add

```
\AtBeginBiblist{shorthand}{\togglefalse{abx@bool@giveninits}}
```

in your preamble.

There is no need to comment out the `publisher` field manually if you don't want to see it, you can use a source map for that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, sorting=nyt,
  giveninits=true, useprefix=false,
  shorthandibid, shorthandfull,
  addendum=false,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=publisher, null]
    }
  }
}

\AtBeginBiblist{shorthand}{\togglefalse{abx@bool@giveninits}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@bookinbook{briocense1,
author = {Le Grant, Hervé},
authortype = {anon?},
editor = {Morice, Hyacinthe},
title = {Chronicon Briocense},
shorthand = {\emph{Chr. Brioc.}},
pages = {1},
booktitle = {Mémoires pour servir de preuves à l'Histoire ecclésiastique et civile de Bretagne},
date = {1742},
publisher = {Osmont},
address = {Paris},
keywords = {primary},
}
@book{briocense2,
author = {Le Grant, Hervé},
authortype = {anon?},
editor = {Le Duc, Gwenaël and Sterckx, Claude},
translator = {Le Duc, Gwenaël and Sterckx, Claude},
title = {Chronicon Briocense: Chronique de Saint-Brieuc (fin 14e siècle), éditée et traduite d'après les manuscrits BN 6003--BN 8899},
shorthand = {\emph{Chr. St-Brieuc}},
date = {1972},
volume = {1},
publisher = {Imprimerie Simon},
address = {Rennes},
keywords = {primary},
}
@book{dargentre,
author = {d'Argentré, Bertrand},
title = {L'histoire de Bretaigne},
shorthand = {d'Argentré},
date = {1583},
publisher = {J. Duclos},
address = {Rennes},
sortkey = {Argentré, Bertrand},
keywords = {secondary},
}
@book{1341docs,
editor = {Graham-Goering, Erika and Jones, Michael and Yeurc'h, Bertrand},
title = {Aux origines de la guerre de succession de Bretagne: Documents (1341--1342)},
shorthand = {\emph{Documents}},
year = {2019},
publisher = {Presses Universitaires de Rennes/Société d’histoire et d’archéologie de Bretagne},
address = {Rennes},
keywords = {primary},
}
@book{duchesne,
author = {Du Chesne, André},
title = {Histoire de la Maison de Chastillon sur Marne},
shorthand = {Du Chesne},
date = {1621},
publisher = {Cramoisy},
address = {Paris},
keywords = {secondary},
}
@book{froissartamiens,
shorthand = {Froissart Amiens},
author = {Froissart, Jean},
editor = {Diller, George T.},
title = {Chroniques: Livre I, le manuscrit d'Amiens},
date = {1991/1998},
publisher = {Droz},
address = {Geneva},
keywords = {primary},
}
@book{froissart,
shorthand = {Froissart B},
author = {Froissart, Jean},
editor = {Luce, Siméon},
title = {Chroniques de J. Froissart},
date = {1869/1899},
publisher = {Renouard},
address = {Paris},
keywords = {primary},
}
@book{froissartrome,
shorthand = {Froissart Rome},
author = {Froissart, Jean},
editor = {Diller, George T.},
title = {Chroniques: Dernière rédaction du premier livre, édition du manuscrit de Rome Reg. lat. 869},
date = {1972},
publisher = {Droz},
address = {Geneva},
keywords = {primary},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbiblist{shorthand}

I will really back up this statement with some citations.\autocite{briocense1,briocense2,dargentre,1341docs,duchesne,froissartamiens,froissart,froissartrome}
\end{document}
```

[image: List of shorthands with full bibliography entries]

Comment: When I add `shorthandfull` to my biblatex-chicago options, it crops a `Package biblatex Error: No driver found`--any ideas what I should look for that could be causing this?

Comment: @Erika Mhh, not off the top of my head, sorry? Can you try to compile the example in the answer in a new, empty folder, please? If you still get an error upload the entire `.log` file of the LaTeX run to https://pastebin.com/.

Comment: Your example seems to be working, so it's clearly something on my end. I'll investigate.

Comment: @Erika If you type `H` when you get the error message, LaTeX should tell you *which* driver is undefined. Maybe that can already help. The error suggests you are using an entry type like `@flobbel` that `biblatex-chicago` does not know.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed, there was an outdated entry type--I've changed them to `@misc` and we're good to go now. Thanks for the additional help.

Comment: @Erika Great it works! May I ask which type was undefined?

Comment: Yes, it was `@customa`, which (for reasons that are now lost in the mists of time) I had decided to use to add some shorthands that weren't in my standard references to the abbreviation list.

Comment: @Erika Ah, I see. I guess `biblatex-chicago` should have a catch-all alias set up here to avoid the error (at least that is what the standard styles do: they only produce a warning). But on the other hand the error lead you to find out about an issue in your `.bib` files, so it was useful.